# Spring static content not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use resources using Spring MVC. I have a class WebApplicationContextConfig that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and in there I am overriding method addResourceHandlers:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```

In folder resources I have three images. But when I go in browser to get some image, for ex: http://localhost:8080/img/P123.jpeg I got 404 error.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you map an external URI to the physical path where resources are located so a request start with /img is mapped to physical path /resources under the web root application (webapp/resources) so your request should be http://localhost:8080/img/P123.jpeg
- your request should start with your servlet mapping: if your servelt mapping is my-app your request should be http://localhost:8080/my-app/img/P123.jpeg
- check that your resources folder is under webapp folder

Comment: I made a mistake in a url path, of course it was the one that you wrote. However, what do you mean by saying webapp folder? I am placing all images in src/main/resources, should I move it somewhere else?

Comment: Ok so everything is clear now, I had my image in "main" resources folder, not in webapp resources folder, when I moved images to /webapp/resources/ everything is working fine.

Comment: if you put images in src/main/resources the location should be .addResourceLocations("classpath:/");

Comment: So "/" means main project "resources" directory? And if for ex. I create directory "images" in "resources", when adding resource location I should write "/resources/images/"?

Comment: "classpath:/images/" instead

Comment: Yeah that what I wanted to write, dunno why I wrote /resources/ instead of /, ok I know everything now, thanks.